# How to know which type to use when use foreach on an IEnumerable type?

Tags: c#, .net

I have an object which implements IEnumerable interface. In C#, I can use foreach to iterate all its element. However I am wondering how to determine the type in the foreach loop?

Comment: Why do you use the non generic `IEnumerable`? Are you still using .net 1.x?

Comment: Anyway it's not really common to have a IEnumerable of anything that you don't know what's inside. Maybe can you explain the situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an old style `IEnumerable` (not `IEnumerable<T>`) you can usually call `.Cast<T>` or `.OfType<T>` to get a strongly typed one to `.ForEach<T>` over...

If you don't know `T` then you can call `Debug.Write(item.GetType())`

Answer (score 2):

If you are using only IEnumerable you have to use object. If you know the real type then you can cast that object.

You can also use the generic IEnumberable and then you won't need to do the cast.

Comment: `foreach` automatically casts to the type you use for your variable declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try var?

foreach(var item in myEnumerable)
{
   ...
}

Comment: This would not be any different from having object instead of var.

Comment: If the right side is just an IEnumerable then var will become object. So it won't help the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Without having the generic variant of IEumerable there is no nice way of knowing.
You could use the is operator to check first item in enumerable along with different foreach loops but I wouldn't recomend it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the non-generic `IEnumerable` you cannot infer the type of items returned through the interface at compile-time. If you know enough about the object, you may know it only contains a specific type, which means you can (with relative safety) construct a `foreach` loop with the known type. For example, if you know it only returns strings, you can iterate over the object like so:

```
foreach(string s in myObject)
{
    // Do some operation.
}
```

Unfortunately, you can return **any** item from a non-generic `IEnumerable`. If the `IEnumerable` returns a `float`, you will receive an `InvalidCastException` on the first line.

Worse still, there's nothing to prevent the elements being a variety of types within the same sequence. The object could legally return the following types within one `foreach` loop.

1. `string`
2. `int`
3. `float`
4. `DateTime`

If you don't know from the object's documentation, the only other certain way to know the type of any one item in the loop is to check at runtime.

These are the reasons why it's always preferable to use the generic `IEnumerable<T>` over `IEnumerable` when you know your object will only really return one type of value.